# Unable to call another function from Actionlistener

Tags: java, database, actionlistener

I am trying to come up with a simple tool that takes DB Parameters as input from the user in JTextFields and when the user clicks on connect to DB, it uses the input to connect to DB. The UI part is written in a function in the main class from where it is supposed to call the DBConnector class method and pass the input text parameters via the ActionListener. I cannot seem to make the ActionListener part work at all. Here's the main class code below:

```
public class ExcelReportGenerator implements DocumentListener{
//MAIN METHOD
public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                createAndShowUI();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

public ExcelReportGenerator(JButton button1, JButton button2)
{

    button1=this.button1;
    button2=this.button2;

}
private JButton button1 ;
private JButton button2;
private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

//public void DBCaller()
public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
{
    textFields.add( textField );
    textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );

}

public boolean isDataEntered()
{
    for (JTextField textField : textFields)
    {
        if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
{
    checkData();
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
{
    checkData();
}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

private void checkData()
{
    button1.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    button2.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );


}

private static void createAndShowUI()  throws RowsExceededException, ClassNotFoundException, WriteException, SQLException, IOException 
{       
    //CREATING BUTTONS
    JButton submit = new JButton( "Connect To DB" );
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            DBConnector.DBConnection(textField_1.getText(),textField_2.getText(),
                textField_3.getText(),textField_4.getText(),textField_5.getText());

            //NEED TO ACCESS THE DBCONNECTOR CLASS METHOD HERE
        }
    });
    submit.setEnabled(false);
    submit.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.disabledShadow"));
    submit.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    submit.setBounds(282, 77, 192, 36);




    JButton btnExportToExcel = new JButton("Export To Excel");
    btnExportToExcel.setEnabled(false);
    btnExportToExcel.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    btnExportToExcel.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    submit.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.disabledShadow"));
    btnExportToExcel.setBounds(282, 178, 192, 36);


    //DECLARING TEXTFIELDS
    JTextField textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 224));
    JTextField textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 224));
    JTextField textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 224));
    JTextField textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 224));
    JTextField textField_5 = new JTextField();
    textField_5.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 224));
    JTextField textField_6 = new JTextField();
    textField_6.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 224));
    JTextField textField_7 = new JTextField();
    textField_7.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 224));

    //ADDING TEXTFIELDS TO ARRAY THROUGH CONSTRUCTOR
    ExcelReportGenerator de = new ExcelReportGenerator( submit , btnExportToExcel);
    de.addTextField( textField_1 );
    de.addTextField( textField_2 );
    de.addTextField( textField_3 );
    de.addTextField( textField_4 );
    de.addTextField( textField_5 );
    de.addTextField( textField_6 );
    de.addTextField( textField_7 );



    //CREATING THE FRAME
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Report Maker");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,335));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(submit);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnExportToExcel);


    //ALL TEXTFIELDS
    textField_1.setBounds(112, 62, 117, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);




    textField_2.setBounds(112, 93, 117, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);



    textField_3.setBounds(112, 124, 117, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);



    textField_4.setBounds(112, 155, 117, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_4);
    textField_4.setColumns(10);



    textField_5.setBounds(112, 186, 117, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_5);
    textField_5.setColumns(10);



    textField_6.setBounds(112, 219, 117, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_6);
    textField_6.setColumns(10);



    textField_7.setBounds(112, 250, 117, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_7);
    textField_7.setColumns(10);


    //DBConnector.DBConnection(username,password,hostname,port,sid,tablename,filename);
    //ALL LABELS
    JLabel lblDatabaseToExcel = new JLabel("Database To Excel Tool");
    lblDatabaseToExcel.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblDatabaseToExcel.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 20));
    lblDatabaseToExcel.setBounds(123, -11, 351, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblDatabaseToExcel);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblUsername.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblUsername.setBounds(20, 44, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblPassword.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblPassword.setBounds(20, 78, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

    JLabel lblHostname = new JLabel("Hostname:");
    lblHostname.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblHostname.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblHostname.setBounds(20, 109, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblHostname);

    JLabel lblPort = new JLabel("Port:");
    lblPort.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblPort.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblPort.setBounds(20, 140, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPort);

    JLabel lblSid = new JLabel("SID:");
    lblSid.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblSid.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblSid.setBounds(20, 171, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblSid);

    JLabel lblEnterDbDetails = new JLabel("DB Details:");
    lblEnterDbDetails.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblEnterDbDetails.setFont(new Font("Vrinda", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblEnterDbDetails.setBounds(20, 11, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterDbDetails);

    JLabel lblTableviewName = new JLabel("Table/View Name:");
    lblTableviewName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblTableviewName.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblTableviewName.setBackground(new Color(255, 228, 225));
    lblTableviewName.setBounds(20, 203, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblTableviewName);

    JLabel lblEnterNameOf = new JLabel("Enter Name Of File:");
    lblEnterNameOf.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    lblEnterNameOf.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblEnterNameOf.setBounds(20, 235, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterNameOf);


    JLabel lblgeneratedFileLocated = new JLabel("(Generated File Located At C:\\)");
    lblgeneratedFileLocated.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblgeneratedFileLocated.setForeground(new Color(205, 92, 92));
    lblgeneratedFileLocated.setBounds(305, 204, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblgeneratedFileLocated);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
 }
```

Here's the DBConnector Class code below:

```
public class DBConnector implements ActionListener
{
public static void DBConnection(String user,String pword, String host, String portnum, String sidValue, String table, String generatedfile) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException
{
    String username=user;
    String password=pword;
    String hostname=host;
    String port=portnum;
    String sid=sidValue;
    String tablename=table;
    String filename=generatedfile;

    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is the fricking JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Found!");

            Connection con;
            try {

                Properties props=new Properties();
                props.put("user",username);
                props.put("password",password);
                props.setProperty("hostname",hostname);
                props.setProperty("port",port);
                props.setProperty("sid",sid);

                String jdbcurl="jdbc:oracle:oci:@";
                System.out.println();
                con = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(jdbcurl,props);
                } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "             DB Connection Failed,\n Make Sure All Details Entered Are Correct");
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            if (con != null) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to Database\nClick on the Export To Excel Button");
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
                ReportMaker.reportParameters(tablename,filename, con);
            } 
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "             DB Connection Failed,\n Make Sure All Details Entered Are Correct");
            }

}

}
```

Comment: All the code in the ActionListener is commented out, so it doesn't do anything, obviously.

Comment: And `cannot seem to make the ActionListener part work at all` is not helpful. You gotta tell us what problem you are having instead of making us go through all that code and try figure out ourselves.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new to Stack Exchange. Anyway... in the ActionListener part, i Am trying to call the DBConnection function which is in a different  DBConnector Class.  This function should pass the database parameters which the user input in the textFields in the createAndShowUI function in the ExcelReportGenerator class.

But the parameters are not getting read inside the ActionListener function. Clicking on the button should call the DBConnection function with the parameters the user has input in the createAndShowUI function.